# How to change .../wp-admin/... (not just the login page)

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

As a process of white labeling WordPress websites for my clients I was wondering if I can mask admin panel URLs from these:

```
https://www.somerandomaddress.com/wp-admin/index.php

https://www.somerandomaddress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=12&action=edit
```

to these:

```
https://www.somerandomaddress.com/admin/index.php

https://www.somerandomaddress.com/admin/post.php?post=12&action=edit
```

Preferably I don't want to change core WordPress code so official WordPress updates can be applied without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your .htaccess in order to wp work as before and see the url only changed.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ /admin/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use the plugin

[Protect Your Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/)

Comment: already checked it.
It only changes login url, not what I try to change.

Comment: Yes! this is it!